# Filtered change notification on views

Tags: filter, couchdb

I need to replicate, in a new database, the result of a view.
Is there a solution other than using an external process waiting for changes?

Below a broken example of what i need: a continuos filtered replica using a reduced view as source:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d \
'{"source":"http://localhost:5984/datastream/_design/dbname/_view/viewname?group=true&group_level=3", \
"target":"http://localhost:5984/dbreplica", "filter":"dbname/filtername", \
"query_params": {"key":"value"}, "continuous":true}' http://localhost:5984/_replicate
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, but maybe [this new feature of CouchDB-1.1](http://docs.couchbase.org/couchdb-release-1.1/index.html#couchdb-release-1.1-filters) is of some help.

Comment: No these new features don't solve.

Comment: Views don't *generally* fit in databases. It is roughly comparible, keys are doc ids, and values are doc bodies. But views can have duplicate keys and database cannot have duplicate ids. Is that not a problem in your case?

Comment: I wouldn't map view keys in database _ids but in another field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CouchDB supports replicating from one database to another. It is not possible to replicate or copy a view to a database.

However [BigCouch](https://github.com/cloudant/bigcouch), custom couchdb build made by [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/) with built-in clustering capability, has a feature called [chained-map-reduce views](http://support.cloudant.com/kb/views/chained-mapreduce-views). It allows the rows from a map-reduce view to be copied to another database. This is exactly what you are trying to do.